# String.format и class Date. Неправильный год

Tags: java

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws CloneNotSupportedException
{
    Date date = new Date(2000, 0, 1);
    System.out.println(String.format("%tY", date));
    System.out.println(date.getYear());
}
```

Результат:

> **3900** 
> 2000

Почему выводится неправильный год? 
P.S. Знаю что класс Date deprecated.

Answer (score 1):

Если посмотреть на джавадок для конструктора даты то там будет описание первого параметра "year – the year minus 1900".

Comment: Спасибо, понял и принял.

Comment: Это древняя фигня. Была придумана когда год было модно двумя цифрами записывать.